# Active voice and passive voice in Present tense and Present Continues tense

Tags: verb-forms, passive-voice

Passive voice in the present tense:

> I am proved wrong.

Here we are using past participle of the verb "prove".

Why did we do that, given that the sentence is in the present tense? And how can we use the passive voice with the present and present continuous tense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passive voice always uses the 3<sup>rd</sup> (participle) form of the verb, even though the sentence might have any tense:

> I *am* **amazed** by Justin Bieber. (*present*).
>
> I *was* **amazed** by Justin Bieber last night. (*past*).
>
> Justin Bieber *has been* **attacked**. (*present perfect*).
>
> Ludwig van Beethoven *had been* **seen** at least once by his mother before he died. (*past perfect*).
>
> ...

Comment: "Justin Bieber was amaze me last night" -Past tense, Active voice."I was amazed by justin Bieber last night"-Past tense ,Passive voice.  is it correct.

Comment: @user1114 The passive voice version is correct. The active voice version should be "Justin Bieber amazed me last night."

Comment: We use Past participle(3rd form of the verb) in present tense  for passive voice ,where else we can use past participle in present tense.

Comment: @user1114 I don't think there are any other cases.

Comment: @user1114 If this helped, remember to click the "tick" (✔) in this answer to mark it as accepted!

Comment: There are two participial forms, and passive clauses can be made using either one.

Comment: @Abody97, can you give an example of Present Continues Tense, please?

Comment: what are the two participial forms.

Comment: one is Present Participle and second one is past Participle

Comment: @user1114 Yes, and most of the time you'll want the *past participle*, as mentioned by Abody97.  Not always, however--see the ["concealed passive" as described by Geoffrey Pullum](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922), as in "This car needs *washing*."

Answer (score 0):

The difference is who/what is performing the action.

> I am amazing. // Active, I'm the one who amazes others. An adjectival use.
>
> I was amazed. // Passive, I am not currently amazed but I was. I did nothing, someone/something else amazed me.
>
> I am amazed. // Passive, but I am still amazed by something that happened in the past.